# Kendo Angular - How to get data on the doubleClick event on Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to get data on the doubleClick event on Kendo Grid?

I would like to get the same object that I fetch at the selected event, which would be dataitem in the position of IndexRowSelected

Html:

```
<kendo-grid
    #myGrid
    [data]="gridData"
    [selectable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)"
    (dblclick)="doubleClickHandler(myGrid, $event)">
</kendo-grid>
```

TS:

```
onSelection(event){
   //dataItem at row selected
   event.selectedRows[0].dataItem
}

doubleClickHandler(grid, event){

//get dataItem like onSelection function

}
```

dataItem object example:
[{
"id":0,
"name":"Chai",
"category": "Beverages",
"price": "18",
"instock": "39"

}]
[image]
thanks,

Federico

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is handle the SelectionChange event ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-selectionchange)) to get the dataItem from the selected row and then store the value in a private variable.

Then when you handle the double-click event, you'd simply reference the private variable's value.

Component's Template:

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
            [height]="410"
            [selectable]="true"
            (dblclick)="onGridDoubleClicked()"
            (selectionChange)="onGridSelectionChanged($event)">
    <!-- column definitions... -->
</kendo-grid>
```

Component's Typescript:

```js
private selectedRecord: any | undefined;
onGridDoubleClicked(): void {
  // do something with this.selectedRecord
}

onGridSelectionChanged(e: SelectionEvent): void {
  if (!e.selectedRows?.length) {
    return;
  }
  this.selectedRecord = e.selectedRows[0].dataItem;
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4cn9w-phvv6a?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

---

**2024-03-13 Update**

LiborV provided a scenario where this double-click solution could not work as intended. If you select a row and double-click anywhere on the grid (including the header/footer) then it would still trigger the code in the `onGridDoubleClicked` event.

This is problematic and I do not have a good solution to resolve this.

Comment: Note that if you have a row selected, you can double-click on the grid's header or footer and it will still run the onGridDoubleClicked method even your mouse is not even close to the selected row. That might cause some surprises.

Comment: @LiborV - That's a good point. I answered this a year and a half ago and really haven't touched Kendo using Angular probably since then so I'm not sure if this is something they've addressed or not. But I will update my answer to include that caveat.